Heterostructure "relax" calculation is taking too much time
I am performing relax for WS2/CrN heterostructure on QE. It has already taken a month and still not converged.
I am not sure if some parameter is off in my input file. Is there any way to reduce the heterostructure calculation time?
&CONTROL
  calculation = 'relax'
  etot_conv_thr =   2.4000000000d-04
  forc_conv_thr =   1.0000000000d-04
  outdir = '../out/'
  prefix = 'aiida'
  pseudo_dir = '../pseudo/'
  tprnfor = .true.
  tstress = .true.
  verbosity = 'high'
/
&SYSTEM
  degauss =   1.4699723600d-02
  ecutrho =   4.8000000000d+02
  ecutwfc =   6.0000000000d+01
  ibrav = 0
  nat = 24
  nosym = .false.
  nspin = 2
  ntyp = 4
  occupations = 'smearing'
  smearing = 'cold'
  starting_magnetization(1) =   3.5714285714d-01
  starting_magnetization(2) =   1.0000000000d-01
  starting_magnetization(3) =   1.0000000000d-01
  starting_magnetization(4) =   3.5714285714d-01
 /
&ELECTRONS
  conv_thr =   4.8000000000d-09
  electron_maxstep = 150
  mixing_beta =   4.0000000000d-01
  startingpot = 'file'
  startingwfc = 'file'
/
&IONS
ion_dynamics = 'bfgs'
/
&CELL
cell_dynamics = 'bfgs'
press_conv_thr= 0.05
cell_dofree = 'all' 
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Cr     51.9961 cr_pbesol_v1.5.uspp.F.UPF
N      14.0067 N.pbesol-theos.UPF
S      32.065 s_pbesol_v1.4.uspp.F.UPF
W      183.84 w_pbesol_v1.2.uspp.F.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Cr           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 
Cr           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.2953210000 
Cr          -0.0000000000       0.5000000000       0.1476600000 
Cr           0.5000000000       0.0000000000       0.1476600000 
Cr           0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.0000000000 
Cr           0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.2953210000 
N           -0.0000000000       0.5000000000       0.0000000000 
N           -0.0000000000       0.5000000000       0.2953210000 
N            0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.1476600000 
N            0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.1476600000 
N            0.5000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 
N            0.5000000000       0.0000000000       0.2953210000 
W            0.1666670000       0.3333330000       0.6514460000 
W            0.1666670000       0.8333330000       0.6514460000 
W            0.6666670000       0.3333330000       0.6514460000 
W            0.6666670000       0.8333330000       0.6514460000 
S            0.3333330000       0.1666670000       0.5415210000 
S            0.3333330000       0.6666670000       0.5415210000 
S            0.8333330000       0.1666670000       0.5415210000 
S            0.8333330000       0.6666670000       0.5415210000 
S            0.3333330000       0.1666670000       0.7613700000 
S            0.3333330000       0.6666670000       0.7613700000 
S            0.8333330000       0.1666670000       0.7613700000 
S            0.8333330000       0.6666670000       0.7613700000 
K_POINTS automatic
6 6 3 0 0 0
CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom
      6.3684460000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000
     -3.1842230000       5.5152360186       0.0000000000
      0.0000000000       0.0000000000      14.1908550000


Some things you can try: decrease all the thresholds, first optimize only the atom positions, then optimize the cell, do a non spin polarized calculation, etc..

Could you show your output, or if it's too large, only the output of $ grep error your_scf.out so that the convergence trend can be seen? Also, N and S are nonmagnetic. You don't need starting_magnetization(2) =   1.0000000000d-01 and starting_magnetization(3) =   1.0000000000d-01. Lastly, if you don't need stress information, ignore tstress keyword since relax calculation does not need it, vc-relax requires it. It will save up some computational time.

Although N and S are not magnetic however, W and Cr are paramagnetic and antiferromagnetic, respectively. Is it fine to not include magnetization? Or is there any way to introduce magnetization only for W and Cr?
